# Merge per group to fill time series

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to merge two dataframes per group in order to fill time for each user. Consider the following pyspark dataframes,

```
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(
    [
        ('2018-03-01 00:00:00', 'A', 5),
        ('2018-03-01 03:00:00', 'A', 7),
        ('2018-03-01 02:00:00', 'B', 3),
        ('2018-03-01 04:00:00', 'B', 2)
     ],
     ('datetime', 'username', 'count')
)

#and

df1 = sqlContext.createDataFrame(
    [
        ('2018-03-01 00:00:00',1),
        ('2018-03-01 01:00:00', 2),
        ('2018-03-01 02:00:00', 2),
        ('2018-03-01 03:00:00', 3),
        ('2018-03-01 04:00:00', 1),
        ('2018-03-01 05:00:00', 5)
    ],
    ('datetime', 'val')
)
```

which produce,

```
+-------------------+--------+-----+
|           datetime|username|count|
+-------------------+--------+-----+
|2018-03-01 00:00:00|       A|    5|
|2018-03-01 03:00:00|       A|    7|
|2018-03-01 02:00:00|       B|    3|
|2018-03-01 04:00:00|       B|    2|
+-------------------+--------+-----+

#and 

+-------------------+---+
|           datetime|val|
+-------------------+---+
|2018-03-01 00:00:00|  1|
|2018-03-01 01:00:00|  2|
|2018-03-01 02:00:00|  2|
|2018-03-01 03:00:00|  3|
|2018-03-01 04:00:00|  1|
|2018-03-01 05:00:00|  5|
+-------------------+---+
```

The column `val` from `df1` is irrelevant and not needed in the final outcome so we can drop it. At the end, the expected result would be,

```
+-------------------+--------+-----+
|           datetime|username|count|
+-------------------+--------+-----+
|2018-03-01 00:00:00|       A|    5|
|2018-03-01 01:00:00|       A|    0|
|2018-03-01 02:00:00|       A|    0|
|2018-03-01 03:00:00|       A|    7|
|2018-03-01 04:00:00|       A|    0|
|2018-03-01 05:00:00|       A|    0|
|2018-03-01 00:00:00|       B|    0|
|2018-03-01 01:00:00|       B|    0|
|2018-03-01 02:00:00|       B|    3|
|2018-03-01 03:00:00|       B|    0|
|2018-03-01 04:00:00|       B|    2|
|2018-03-01 05:00:00|       B|    0|
+-------------------+--------+-----+
```

I have tried to `groupBy()` and `join` but that did not work. I have also tried to create a function and register it as `pandas_udf()`, but still did not work, i.e.

```
df.groupBy('usernames').join(df1, 'datetime', 'right')
```

and

```
@pandas_udf('datetime string, username string, count double', F.PandasUDFType.GROUPED_MAP)
def fill_time(df):
    return df.merge(df1, on = 'cdatetime', how = 'right')
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just cross product distinct timestamps and user names and outer join back with the data:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import broadcast

(broadcast(df1.select("datetime").distinct())
    .crossJoin(df.select("username").distinct())
    .join(df, ["datetime", "username"], "leftouter")
    .na.fill(0))
```

To use `pandas_udf` you'll need a local object as a reference

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import PandasUDFType, pandas_udf

def fill_time(df1):
    @pandas_udf('datetime string, username string, count double', PandasUDFType.GROUPED_MAP)
    def _(df):
        df_ = df.merge(df1, on='datetime', how='right')
        df_["username"] = df_["username"].ffill().bfill()
        return df_
    return _

(df.groupBy("username")
    .apply(fill_time(
        df1.select("datetime").distinct().toPandas()
    ))
    .na.fill(0))
```

but it will be slower than the SQL only solution.